# How to use content property of css in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px),(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

    td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }

}
```

How to do in jQuery?

Comment: I already do this but it is not working

Comment: Duplicate question - otherwise like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WsZMm/